# C - scanning only words between "--"s from txt file without regex

Tags: c

For example, I have lots of text files and they're like

```
Tags: --Maths--, --Physics--, --Programming--, ...

Some other text about subject and --another tag-- inside this text..
```

Every word between "--"s are tags. Each one of text files have different tags and some of them have same tags. Number of tags can be more or less than 3 in each file. I need to scan words between "--"s and count them. Then print it to screen.

Example output that I need:

```
Tag Name    - Number
Maths       - 4 times
Physics     - 6 times
Programming - 2 times
```

I've tried this code to get tag names:

```
FILE *srcFile;

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        srcFile = fopen(pathArr[i], "r"); // pathArr has all paths of my txt files to search
        
        char tagArr[100][100]; // array to store all tags
        char tagName[100];
        int arrIndex = 0;

        fscanf(srcFile, "--%s--", tagName);
        strcpy(tagArr[arrIndex++], tagName);

        fclose(srcFile);
    }
```

but it doesn't work because there's more than one tag in each file and this only gets one of them, I guess?

I don't know I can do this or not with regex but I'm not allowed to use it anyway. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need a nested loop to read the whole file, you only do one `fscanf` per file now. How does `[[%s]]` match with your tags if they are enclosedin `--*--`?

Comment: Can a tag contain a newline? (eg, can the opening `--` appear on a different line 
than the closing `--`?). What do you do with a line that looks like `foo -- bar`?  (mismatched `--`).

Comment: I *strongly* recommend you avoid `scanf` for this.  In the end, it will be less work and you will learn more if you use `getchar` and build a state machine.

Comment: @Gerhardh sorry, it's `--%s--`. i fixed it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, a tag cannot contain a new line. I dont think any of my text files will look like that.

Comment: Valid reasons to use C for this task: 1. Homework 2. Wanting to learn C by example. Valid reasons NOT to use C for this task: 1. Productivity (getting it done quickly) 2. Reliability 3. Performance * Productivity (getting it really fast in a reasonable amount of time). At least, you should pick a language, which supports basic data structures, like Dictionaries/Maps and Vectors instead of picking the one, forcing you implement it all yourself.

Comment: @BitTickler It's homework. I don't want to use C too.

Comment: 3rd valid reason to use C for this: entertainment /fun!!

Comment: @WilliamPursell You could increase that kind of fun even more by resorting to x86-64 assembly language. Or better yet - just design your own device with VHDL ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an extremely naive approach that should get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct tag {
    const char *name;
    int count;
    struct tag *p[2];
};

int
get_tag(char *buf, const char *end)
{
    int c, prev = 0;
    /* Discard data until `--` */
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF ){
        if( c == '-' && prev == '-' ){
            break;
        }
        prev = c;
    }
    prev = 0;
    /* Read in a tag.  TODO: handle whitespace better */
    if( c != EOF ){
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && buf < end ){
            if( c == '-'  && prev == '-' ){
                assert(buf[-1] == '-');
                buf[-1] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            prev = *buf++ = c;
        }
    }
    if( c == EOF ){
        return EOF;
    }
    if( buf == end ){
        fputs("Absurdly long tag found! Aborting!\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}


void
push(struct tag **tp, const char *n)
{
    struct tag *t = *tp;
    int cmp;
    if( t == NULL ){
        *tp = t = malloc(sizeof *t);
        if( t == NULL ){
            perror("malloc");
            exit(1);
        }
        t->name = strdup(n);
        t->count = 1;
        t->p[0] = t->p[1] = NULL;
    } else if( (cmp = strcmp(n, t->name)) == 0 ){
        t->count += 1;
    } else {
        push(&t->p[cmp > 0], n);
    }
}


void
walk(struct tag *t)
{
    if( t ){
        walk(t->p[0]);
        printf("%25s - %d\n", t->name, t->count);
        walk(t->p[1]);
    }
}


int
main(void)
{
    char buf[1024];
    struct tag *tags = NULL;

    while( get_tag(buf, buf + sizeof buf) != EOF ){
        push(&tags, buf);
    }

    printf("%25s - %s\n", "Tag Name", "Number");
    walk(tags);

}
```

This does not handle invalid input at all well. (For example, a reasonable person would take `--Maths--` and `--  Maths--` (with whitespace) to be the same token, and the program should probably discard unmatched `--` rather than incorporating an enclosing newline into the tag name, and strings like `-------` should be handled somewhat cleanly.)  Dealing with such details is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Would you mind teaching how you use -1 as an index in buf[-1]? Doesn't an array start from 0?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire `buf` in `get_tag` is not an array, it is a pointer.  Pointers are not arrays.  Arrays are not pointers.  `buf[-1]` is short hand for `*(buf - 1)`. In this context, `buf` is pointing into an array (the variable `buf` in `main`, which is an array), but it is not pointing at the first element. At this point in the code we know that it has advanced at least one, because we can only be in that branch if the previous character was `-`, and that logic is verified by the assertion.