# Parsing string between two sets of characters without regex

Tags: c, parsing, c-strings

Say we have a string that goes like "((the)) weather is usually good ((when)) its ((spring))"
How can I parse only the words between '((' and '))' without using regex.

Comment: Do you know _stack structure_?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C - scanning only words between "--"s from txt file without regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070650/c-scanning-only-words-between-s-from-txt-file-without-regex)

Comment: The question is underspecified; both answers depend on their own (different) interpretations. So you should be cautious: first, figure out the precise requirement. (And then, if you think it is necessary, write a new question, but please don't just ask "How do I do this task?", which is too broad for SO.

Comment: The underspecification: What is the intent if there are parentheses inside the double-parenthesised brackets? `This (((has two unbalanced ()), while (((this is perfectly balanced)))`. You have a number of options: (1) Forbid inner parentheses. (2) Insist that inner parentheses balance; don't terminate until you find a balancing `))`. (3) Allow arbitrary single parentheses, but require inner `((` to balance `))`. (4) Close the parenthetic expression at the first `))` regardless of other parentheses. (And many others.) None of these are totally satisfactory, so there is no default choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strstr()` defined in `<string.h>` to search for `"(("`, then search from there for `"))"` to find the end of the match:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *get_word(const char *s, size_t *pos) {
    const char *p1;  // pointer to the next match
    const char *p2;  // pointer to the match end
    p1 = strstr(s + *pos, "((");
    if (p1 == NULL) {
        *pos += strlen(s + *pos);
        return NULL;
    }
    p1 += 2;
    p2 = strstr(p1, "))");
    if (p2 == NULL) {
        // missing end string
        *pos += strlen(s + *pos);
        return NULL;
    }
    *pos = p2 + 2 - s;
    return strndup(p1, p2 - p1);  // allocate a copy of the match
}

int main() {
    const char *str = "((the)) weather is usually good ((when)) it's ((spring))";
    size_t pos = 0;
    char *p;

    while ((p = get_word(s, &pos)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", p);
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```